# Gmail messages still auto-forwarded after destination email was removed

Tags: gmail

I set up a forward mail from my Gmail account (say B) to Gmail A. Every mail received in B gets forwarded to A and no copy of it is retained in B. Now I don't want that to happen. I want my emails for B to be stored in B. So I deleted my email address A from B's forward option. But still the mail gets forwarded from B to A. How do I stop this?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if it takes some time for the settings to propagate. In the meantime, make sure you don't have a stray filter moving things about.

Comment: Its been a long time.

Comment: How long is "a long time"? And how long was the forward set up for?

Comment: almost a month ago.

Comment: I tried to add the mail A as forwarding mail now just to check it. It sent a verification mail to mail A. I clicked on "don't allow for auto-forwarding mail from mail B". and i check it again. Still the result is same. All the primary mail in B gets forwarded to mail A.

Comment: The forward was set up for almost 3 months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This configuration sounds like you have actually have setup **POP Download** or **IMAP Access**. On both accounts check that these two settings are **disabled**.

1. **Settings**
2. **Forwarding and POP/IMAP** tab.
3. Select **Disable POP**
4. Select **Disable IMAP**
5. Click on **Save Changes**

[image]